# How would I go about eliminating duplicates in a update query that includes a concat

Tags: mysql

Here is the query I have to call each time a new item is added to the database :

```
UPDATE `cas_phocagallery`,`cas_phocagallery_categories`
   SET cas_phocagallery.description=concat(
       cas_phocagallery_categories.title,'<br />',cas_phocagallery.description)
 WHERE cas_phocagallery.catid = cas_phocagallery_categories.id;
```

It works fine except that it produces a duplicate each time I run the query.
I tried to add distinct but I get an error and I am not sure this is the right thing to do in this case.

Thank you for your cooperation, I have been looking at all kinds of ways all day with no success.

Comment: This is not a query.  It is a DML (Data Manipulation Language) statement.  If you have a unique key on this column it will produce and error each time after first successful update.

Comment: Thank you for rectification, I am so not an expert and trying very hard to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you run the query, you add the `title` to the current `description`. If you run it three times in a row, you will get

```
title    <-- added by 3rd
title    <-- added by 2nd
title    <-- added by 1st
description (original)
```

Is that what you mean?  That is exactly what the query is designed to do. Maybe you need another column to keep the "base_description", so that each time, "description" gets to be "title" + br + "base_description"

---

#### EDIT

You can try something like this, which would work 95% of the time, until the title changes in which case you will get the historical titles built up.  It also doesn't work when the title contains the `%` symbol and may work funny if it contains the `_` character.

```
UPDATE cas_phocagallery, cas_phocagallery_categories
   SET cas_phocagallery.description=concat(
       cas_phocagallery_categories.title,'<br />',cas_phocagallery.description)
 WHERE cas_phocagallery.catid = cas_phocagallery_categories.id
   AND NOT cas_phocagallery.description
           LIKE concat(cas_phocagallery_categories.title, '%')
```

Can't really comment on Joomla or how it does things or why this would be necessary (to merge title into description).  What you should really do is in some SELECT statement in some module, show the result of the CONCAT instead of persisting (pushing/mangling) it into description.

```
   SELECT cas_phocagallery.*, concat(cas_phocagallery_categories.title,
                                     '<br />',
                                     cas_phocagallery.description) as FullDescription
     FROM cas_phocagallery
LEFT JOIN cas_phocagallery_categories
       ON cas_phocagallery.catid = cas_phocagallery_categories.id
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. Actualy what I need to do is add the title of the item which is in one table to the description which is in another table. And both items are part of a module generated in joomla. So I am not sure an update is the proper action to take. I am really not that good at programming mysql and this action has to be inserted in php and called from the admin menu in joomla. Do you need more information?

Comment: It's working perfectly, exactly what I needed.  What did you mean by Care to explain the downvote? How do I go about voting?

Answer (score 1):

When you have a unique key, it should produce an error when inserting a duplicate value and is expected behaviour. I think what you should be looking at is [on duplicate key update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) where you can specify what to do if a duplicate is found.

Comment: He is not inserting, he is updating.

Comment: since none of the columns called are unique, how would I go about using on duplicate key update? Actualy what I need to do is add the title of the item which is in one table to the description which is in another table. And both items are part of  a module generated in joomla. So is update the right option to use, I am really not an expert at mysql.

Comment: You can create unique indexes in MySQL on multiple columns. Read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html for the syntax. The on duplicate key will get fired when there is a duplicate based on the column combination and you can use an appropriate SQL statement to action the duplicate (such as updating the existing record, adding a value to a log table, etc.)